# Where in Rails to fill in gaps in time series?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, architecture

My basic set of models looks roughly like this (simplified):

```
[ PayPeriod ]
id
start_date
end_date
notes

[ Transaction ]
id
amount
fkPayPeriod
```

When a user logs in, I want to present them with a list of the last 4 pay periods.  The user can select a pay period to enter notes and transactions.

I'm inclined to just do something like this in the controller:

```
def index
  @pay_periods = PayPeriod.get_or_create_last(4)
end
```

The PayPeriod model itself would implement the behavior, and records would be created "on demand" as users used the app.

An alternative approach might be to have some other (background) process that combs through accounts on a daily basis to proactively create new PayPeriods.  Although neither solution strikes me as particularly challenging, I'd like to get some feedback on where others feel this functionality belongs conceptually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it depends on what a `PayPeriod` is, conceptually. Is it a universal description of time periods on a common calendar (i.e., the year 2011 has 26 pay periods of two weeks each)? If so, then the creation of all the `PayPeriods` belongs in your db/seeds.rb file.

If a `PayPeriod` belongs to an account, I'd say that the creation of the last four `PayPeriods` belongs in an `after_create` hook on the account in question. Going forward from there, I think the best practice would be to create new `PayPeriods` as your user needs them; that is, the first time I go to add notes or a transaction to a `PayPeriod` is probably when it should get created.

If for any reason you have a system policy in place that allows users to edit a specific window of `PayPeriods` (e.g., you can edit this and the next calendar year), then you might set up a Rake task and hook it up to a Cron job that runs it however often it needs to be run (e.g., if you're limiting your window by calendar year, then you could set up a Cron job to run every January 1 at 12:01am that creates the year's `PayPeriods`).